# Yii2 - Globally registering assets with twig

Tags: yii2, twig, yii-extensions, yii2-basic-app, twig-extension

I have the following as the first two lines in my `site\index.twig` file.

```
{{ use('app/assets/AppAsset') }}
{{ register_app_asset() }}
```

My query is that is it possible to do this in the `config/web.php` file instead?

As for example I am able to do `{{ use('yii/bootstrap') }}` in `layout/main.twig` or instead add the following code to my `config/web.php` file.

```
// setting up twig
'view' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\View',
    'renderers' => [
        'twig' => [
            'class' => 'yii\twig\ViewRenderer',
                ...
                'uses' => [ 'yii\bootstrap' ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

So I wondering if something is able to do be done to register assets also.

Comment: Did you tried add `app\assets\AppAsset` to `uses`?

Comment: @rob006 yes I tried that, but that just means I don't need the `{{ use('app/assets/AppAsset') }}` line, the `{{ register_app_asset() }}` line is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automagically register this asset, you may use [`beginPage` event](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-view#EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE-detail) to call `app\assets\AppAsset::register()` before every layout rendering.

But you probably should not do this. If asset is specific to your layout, it should be registered at layout level (for example in `layouts/main.twig`). Registering it globally at View level will give you a lot of problems if you will need to use different layout (for different theme or layout specific for 3rd-party module, like debug module) in your app. Usually you have only one main file for layout, so you need to place

```
{{ use('app/assets/AppAsset') }}
{{ register_app_asset() }}
```

only in one file (`layouts/main.twig`). Even if you you have several layouts, it is better to repeat this in every file, than create some magic solutions to do it implicitly.

Comment: yes am aware I could do that, and have done so, but I didn't like having the two blank lines in the html output when the source is viewed, and yes I realise it's possible to put them all on one line with <html> at the end.  But then the twig template doesn't then look as neat when viewed in a text editor for example.

Comment: @AeroMaxx So you're sacrificing code maintainability and creating some weird workarounds to avoid 2 empty lines in website source? :O Nobody cares how the source of your website looks like...

Comment: No I never said I was sacrifing code maintainability and creating some wierd workarounds.  I was merely asking if there was another way to do it!

Every layout is going to use assets so why not register it globally, I don't see the issue here.  Just how many websites do you know that don't use any CSS or JavaScript these days?

Comment: @AeroMaxx But you're registering specific assets, not CSS and JS in general. One layout may need CSS and JS from this assets bundle, another may be completely broken because of it. If assets are specific for layout, it should be registered in layout. Doing it globally just makes code less readable and creates problems in future. You just complicating simple task because of completely irrelevant thing (white chars in HTML source).

Comment: I disagree I am wanting to register the CSS and JS that is in the assets/AppAsset.php file, all CSS and JS is added to this file as far as I can tell.

These lines are in that file

 `
  public $css = [
   'css/site.css',
  ];
  public $js = [
  ];
 `